# where does this object come from

Tags: python, object

I'm a relatively new programmer, and i'm in the process of making a game. I am using some code from my previous project which ran fine. But now when i try to call a certain function, which i don't think should need any parameters, it returns some strange errors.

i have this class which i have copied from my previous project:

```
import pyglet as p


class Button(object):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y, text, on_clicked):
        self._width = image.width
        self._height = image.height
        self._sprite = p.sprite.Sprite(image, x, y)
        self._label = p.text.Label(text,
                                  font_name='Times New Roman',
                                  font_size=20,
                                  x=x + 20, y=y + 15,
                                  anchor_x='center',
                                  anchor_y='center')
        self._on_clicked = on_clicked  # action executed when button is clicked

    def contains(self, x, y):
        return (x >= self._sprite.x - self._width // 2
            and x < self._sprite.x + self._width // 2
            and y >= self._sprite.y - self._height // 2
            and y < self._sprite.y + self._height // 2)

    def clicked(self, x, y):
        if self.contains(x, y):
            self._on_clicked(self)

    def draw(self):
        self._sprite.draw()
        self._label.draw()
```

i have my window event that calls the function (w is the window):

```
@w.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    for button in tiles:
        button.clicked(x, y)
```

and three variations of the function it calls that each has a different 'errors':

```
def phfunc(a):
    print(a)
```

returns this thing: `<Button.Button object at 0x0707C350>`

```
def phfunc(a):
    print('a')
```

returns: a
which it actually should

```
def phfunc():
    print('a')
```

returns a long list of callbacks resulting in this:

```
  File "C:\Google Drive\game programmeren\main.py", line 15, in on_mouse_press
    button.clicked(x, y)
  File "C:\Google Drive\game programmeren\Button.py", line 25, in clicked
    self._on_clicked(self)
TypeError: phfunc() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

my best guess is that the argument it has is the self from the Button class. is this correct, and should i worry about this?

Comment: `self` is passed implicitly when you call methods on objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the function reference stored in `self._on_clicked` with `self` as a parameter. `self` is the instance of your `Button` class:

```
self._on_clicked(self)
```

The default representation for your custom `Button` class is `<Button.Button object at 0x0707C350>`.

Since you did so explicitly, that is not something to worry about.